# How to use a value returned in a different class?

Tags: java, class, greatest-common-divisor

This is probably a very simple question. Say I had a class that computed the gcd, called Gcdcomp. The code in that class all works. When i refer to it in my main block of code, I say..

```
Gcdcomp.getGcd(a, hii);
```

a and hii are my two variables. By default, the Getgcd class uses int a and int b and will return a after executing euclids algorithm. How do I use that returned value as a variable in my main code?

Comment: Would be useful to know the declaration of Gcdcomp.getGcd()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result of a function call directly to a variable, like this (assuming that getGcd returns an int):

```
int result = Gcdcomp.getGcd(a, hii);
```

Or if result is already declared beforehand, you can omit the declaration, like this:

```
result = Gcdcomp.getGcd(a, hii);
```

Comment: Yep, that was very easy. Thank you : ) I will accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int gcd = Gcdcomp.getGcd(a, hii);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern for using methods:

```
int myMethod(int x) {
    int y = x * 3;
    return y;
}

...

int z = myMethod(57);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a get method that would return that value.